# TypeORM: How can I have a string array property on an entity backed by a one-to-many?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to find a way to have an entity property that is a string array, which behind the scenes is persisted as a one-to-many relationship.

**Setup:**

```js
@Entity()
class Author {
    @Column()
    firstName: string;
    
    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    books: string[];
    
    @OneToMany(type => [Book], book => book.author)
    private _books: Book[];
}

@Entity()
class Book {
    @Column()
    title: string;
    
    @ManyToOne(type => Author, author => author.books)
    author: Author;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
// Given an author with ID=1 exists
const author = repository.findOne(1);

// Given author.books === []
author.books = [ 'One', 'Two' ]
// and/or:
author.books.push('Three')

// 3 Book records are created with titles 'One', 'Two', and 'Three', and authorId set to 1.
await repository.save(author);
```

**Things I have tried:**
This has turned out to be more difficult than expected.

- **`@BeforeInsert()` / `@BeforeUpdate()` / `@AfterLoad()` Hooks**
  In theory this should be the solution, simply transforming the Book entities into strings after loading, and back to Book entities before saving. Unfortunately, by the time these hooks are invoked, it is too late to add/remove/change related records (see: [TypeORM PR #2383](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2383)).
- **`get()` / `set()` Accessor Functions**
  Transforming an incoming array in set to an entity array works but only when setting the entire array. It can't handle cases where the existing array is modified.
- **Proxying an Array**
  I've partially implemented this (see: [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)), intercepting all access to numeric properties. This seems like overkill and implementing it is becoming increasingly complex and messy. Not sure this is the right way to go.